# How do I get my question re-opened?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question about getting a cool view in NYC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62608/whats-the-cheapest-place-i-can-get-a-high-rise-view-in-new-york-city), which was at least somewhat well-received, indicating it could be helpful to other people.

It was closed as a travel-agent question, and I'm not sure why. I don't know much about NYC and where I could get the sort of view like I'm looking for. The comments seemed to indicate the only real chance is Manhattan, which I didn't know. But more than likely, there's cheaper parts of Manhattan. I wasn't asking for a specific hotel -- maybe that's why people wanted to close it? -- rather a neighborhood(s) to look in.

Once it was closed, I asked why, and the only response I got was to add more details, which seems completely counter-intuitive to me. Asking for the cheapest hotel room with a view on a specific date seems far less broadly applicable than a general question of **What's the cheapest neighborhood in NYC with a view like this?** After telling me to add more details, I got no further response and my attempt to clarify was completely abandoned.

I'd still like to know the answer to my question, so how can I reformulate my question to make it on-topic/answerable?

Comment: Maybe it'd be better if it wasn't "Please find [...] for me" but instead was "How to find [...]"? I have no idea how I'd filter New York hotels by what kind of view they have as well as price, but I'd love to find out - this "teach a man to fish" approach would also eliminate the price fluctuation and "feeling like a travel agent" issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't vote to close your question but I would have if I saw it in the review queue.  I would close as 'unclear what you are asking'.

My immediate reaction to the question was that it was something off-the-wall. You have a photo that highlights St Patrick's and looking down 5th Avenue and want a comparable view for USD 150 per night. Honestly... You want mid-town Manhattan with a gorgeous view for that kind of money?  And it looks like you didn't do some preliminary foundation research.

Point 1:  Part of the 'ethos' on the site is to treat questions as serious when it's clear that the OP has done some foundation research.  I spent 30 seconds in Google and found "[10 NYC Hotels with the Best Views](http://www.newyork.com/articles/hotels/10-hotels-with-the-best-views-84981/)".  Those hotels are out of reach for your budget but at least the research could temper your expectations to be more realistic. Lots of times questions that have unrealistic expectations will be referred to travel agents.

Point 2: Hotel prices in NYC are volatile; they are driven up and down by events, by season, and even by day of week. You didn't provide any of that information.  Are you going on the 4th of July for example? Thanksgiving? Dog days? When vital information is missing, people will vote to close as 'unclear'.

Point 3: Foundation research again:  "*...Being close to the airport would be nice (don't know which one I'm flying to yet) but that's just an extra...*" Conflicting objectives also make it 'unclear'. A very quick glance at Google Maps reveals the only locale that remotely fits these objectives puts you Astoria, is it worth it?

So in its current state, the question should remain closed. In the absence of substantive modifications I would vote *against* reopening it.

**How do I get my question re-opened?**

Read the FAQ on how to compose a great question.  You can then edit the question to give it laser-like focus and add enough info so that a *precise* answer can be provided, one of which will be superior to all the others.  Then *accept* it as [an expression of courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

As a side-note, [West New York (New Jersey)](http://www.westnewyorknj.org/) has [spectacular views](https://www.flickr.com/photos/drunkcat/3049580133) of the Manhattan sky line, and prices in Hudson County/Bergen County are dead cheap!  There's buses to Mid-Town about every 20 minutes. There are comparable views in Brooklyn Heights, but a lot more pricey. Your best bet at your budget is to look through AirBnB for something in the Upper East Side (70's up to 90's) or Blvd East in West New York.  If you go in the week between Christmas and New Year's you can find opulent hotels in the financial district for ridiculously low prices.

Comment: You seem to imply that the answer is simply “It can't be done”. How does that make the question unclear? To me, that proves it's actually sufficiently clear to be answered objectively, even if disappointingly.

Comment: @Relaxed, you may be reading too much into it; please stick with the natural meaning of the words rather than what I 'seem to imply'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems I slightly misunderstand the "travel agent" angle. As for the price, I asked that *because* I couldn't find any that cheap, and was hoping someone had an angle exactly like you posted at the bottom of your answer! I did say when I was going, in May. I thought it was better to be less specific, in the interest of being generalizable. How many other people want to know where to find the cheapest hotel with a view in NYC on May 12, 2016? However, I accept your explanation to that end. As to Astoria: I have no idea whether that's worth it. What's wrong with Astoria

Comment: @Azor-Ahai, in a word: the N Line. But that's a topic for a different site